# How to close a window programmatically in Cocoa Mac?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, window, xib

How can I programmatically close a window in cocoa mac ? I have opened a second window/xib from the first window/xib using button click. I need to close the first window/xib programmatically on opening or clicking the button. How can I do that?

Comment: for orderOut it's showing our firstView may not respond to orderOut!

Comment: tried [window close]; before but it didn't work!

Comment: firstView is my first sib class

Comment: What’s the name of the outlet connected to the first window?

Comment: Surprisingly, this doesn't seem to be a dupe, so I've provided an answer in the interest of SO completeness. It's just code; as @dreamlax's comments imply, there's not much discussion to be had here.

Comment: `firstView` sounds like the name of an `NSView`, not an `NSWindow`. If it is indeed an `NSWindow`, then it will respond if youdo `[window orderOut:nil]` (the `:nil` is very important here).

Comment: @dreamlax-> yea! right! now it worked out well! :) it was just view not NSWindow! when I tried with NSWindow it worked out well. Thank you for the nice help. :)

Comment: @Bavarious-> Actually I was not trying to close the NSWindow directly! & your question started the spark of thought! thanks...

Comment: @dreamlax-> actually your first reply itself should have worked fine if I were a little more careful about NSView & NSWindow. Thank you. :)

Comment: @josh caswell-> new to stackoverflow! and new to cocoa! you explained pretty much more via the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apple has some useful sample code on [Nib Loading](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaTipsAndTricks/Listings/NibLoading_NibLoadingAppDelegate_m.html). It doesn't directly address this question however; the following code does.

```
@interface CloseWindowAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
    IBOutlet NSWindow * secondWindow;
    NSNib * secondNib;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

- (IBAction)openSecondWindow:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)closeSecondWindow:(id)sender;

@end
```

---

```
#import "CloseWindowAppDelegate.h"

@implementation CloseWindowAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

- (IBAction)openSecondWindow:(id)sender {
    secondNib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"SecondWindow" bundle:nil];
    [secondNib instantiateNibWithOwner:self topLevelObjects:nil];
    [secondWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];

}

- (IBAction)closeSecondWindow:(id)sender {
    [secondWindow close];
    [secondNib release];

}

@end
```

Comment: > well explained code. Found very useful. New to stackoverflow and pretty much impressed. Here people like you are explaining very well. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Josh-> it worked well. thank you. Your code found useful regarding the problem I was facing. :)

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for this for ages! 
A simple

```
[self close];
[self release];
```

worked for me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is for someone who is using `Swift` and `NSStoryBoardSegue`, here is the same way to achieve it

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainWindow?.close() // close current window first
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("id_of_your_segue", sender: self) // open the second view by invoking the segue that is set to connect  two views.
```

Answer (score 0):

U may use "performClose" action. Choose nib file (your window which u wont closed), open Connections inspector, connect "performClose" action with u button.